# CommandError: You appear not to have the 'cqlsh' program installed or on your path

Tags: django, django-admin

In Django with Cassandra , while running the #python manage.py dbshell

Casssandra is running and we could able to run the #python manage.py sycn_cassandra and it created the tables in the DB. But dbshell failes with following error . Same command ran in dos prompt

"
CommandError: You appear not to have the 'cqlsh' program installed or on your
path."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I also faced the same issue. Created a symlink in bin

**sudo ln -s /opt/apache-cassandra-3.9/bin/cqlsh /usr/bin/cqlsh**

Its working fine now.